# How can I create a pause for rotating animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-spinner

I need to know how I to pause my rotating animation:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
   ImageView animationTarget = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImgWheel);

   switch (v.getId())
   {
      case R.id.playButton:

      playBtn.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
      pauseBtn.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
      Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_around_center_point);
      animationTarget.startAnimation(animation);
      break;

      case R.id.pauseButton:

      pauseBtn.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
      playBtn.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);

      //here is where i may put the pause button codes//

      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `animationTarget.clearAnimation()` try if helps

Answer (score 0):

```
public void pauseAnimation(View view) {
anim.pause();
//you need to define anim
```

Comment: you need to close pauseAnimation just put } at the end i forget to do so while editting

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.